# Viewing History of a File across different computers

Tags: file, logging

Hellos,

i developed php, png, jpeg, js, html, css files on a windows computer. i uploaded them on a linux centOS server.

Someone harvested or downloaded them, did some modifications on some of them and uploaded them on their server.

I now have harvested or downloaded them from their server and need court admissible proof that He actually copied my works.

Is there a way or is it even possible that, i can view operations on a given file, more like;

- created on 01/02/2014 by (My-Computer-02)
- Read on 12/05/2014 by (His-Computer54)
- Modified on 12/05/2014 by (His-Computer54)

basically something to show that the file was created by my computer and then accessed and or modified by the "frauder's" computer. I know computer names usually give identity of a person or organisation.

Will be glad for your advice, maybe a tool i can run the file on, etc.

Comment: You may wish to try http://law.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Thanx, that was helpful